# Can I connect a SATA 3 cable to a SATA 2 connector, and through some hacks, receive SATA 3 performance?

Tags: ssd, sata, compatibility

I was looking around for an SSD. I found some SATA 3 drives, at the same price as SATA 2 drives. My motherboard however, can't handle SATA 3. Is there any way I can connect SATA 3 drive and get full speed? Possible through some hacks.

One hack I was thinking is for example some controller that will take one SATA 3 cable, then splits it into two SATA 2 cables, so i can connect it to my motherboard.

Comment: It's worth noting that the official SATA spec states and [real world tests](http://www.maximumpc.com/article/features/your_sata_cable_slowing_down_your_data_transfers_max_pc_investigates) have shown that SATA 1 cables do not slow down SATA 6Gbps connections. SATA 3 compliant cables have the extra feature of snapping in when attached so the (already small) chance they'll fall out is further reduced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use SATA3 drives on your SATA2 setup, but it will only run at 3Gbps.

If you want 6Gbps, you can buy a SATA3 6Gbps controller add-on card.

[StarTech makes some](http://ca.startech.com/Cards-Adapters/HDD-Controllers/SATA-Cards?filter_SATATYPE=SATA+III+(6+Gbps)), and I'm sure other's do as well.

Here's a [NewEgg search](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007531&IsNodeId=1&Description=sata%206%20gbps&name=Add-On%20Cards&Order=BESTMATCH) for example.

Comment: And this works when the motherboard does not support SATA 3?

Comment: That's the point. :)  Just make sure they offer drivers for your OS.

Answer (score 0):

That will not work. Your best bet would be to get two SATAII drives and configure them in a RAID 0. This would essentially give you a max of 300MBs per SATAII port and a total of 600MBs bandwidth. Your OS would see the RAID 0 as one partition.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_0

Comment: I know that is possible, but it's to expensive - unfortunately. I guess I'll just buy the faster one, so I can use it when I get a SATA 3 compatible mobo.

Comment: @SimonVerbeke: Two 64 GB SSDs do not cost much more than one 128 GB SSD.

Comment: Have you looked into Z68 Motherboards? I'm getting SSD-Like speeds from a Raid 0 500GBx2 7200RPM with SSD Caching (Intel SRT) with a 128GB (64GB Cache).

Comment: All AMD parts here :)